# Get unmodified HTML source code with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, escaping, special-characters

As a basis we have the following HTML page:

```
<html><body>
    <div>Unescaped characters: < > </div>
    <div>Escaped characters: &lt; &gt; </div>
</body></html>
```

Testcase 1: innerHTML and outerHTML (result = both escaped)

```
<div>Unescaped characters: &lt; &gt; </div>
<div>Escaped characters: &lt; &gt; </div>
```

Testcase 2: innerText (result = both unescaped)

```
<div>Unescaped characters: < > </div>
<div>Escaped characters: < > </div>
```

Which javascript function would give me the exact HTML source code as shown at the beginning (one escaped, the other one unescaped)?

Comment: The HTML page you use as a basis is invalid. Angle brackets cannot appear verbatim like that.

Comment: I guess that should not matter for the described problem. In fact I am testing for code injection (e.g. XSS, HTML injection).